# aws web service not available on the internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, tomcat, amazon-ec2

In unix using putty I am able to get a result:

```
  curl http://localhost:8080/products-ut-wo-db/rest/products
```

In security group I have inbound: 8080
    [image]

In /home/ec2-user/java/tomcat9/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml I comment out the valve following:
    [image]

I tried these url nothing come:
http://ec2-18-236-111-143.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/products-ut-wo-db/rest/products
http://ec2-18-236-111-143.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080

Here is my netstat -nat:
 [image]

Here is the /home/ec2-user/java/tomcat9/conf/server.xml:

Here is my /home/ec2-user/java/tomcat9/conf/server.xml:

```
                        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <!--
              Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
              contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
              this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
              The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
              (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
              the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

                  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

              Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
              distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
              WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
              See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
              limitations under the License.
            -->
            <!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
                 define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
                 Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
             -->
            <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
              <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
              <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
              <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
              -->
              <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
              <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
              <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
              <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
              <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
              <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

              <!-- Global JNDI resources
                   Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
              -->
              <GlobalNamingResources>
                <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
                 UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
                -->
                <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
                      type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
                      description="User database that can be updated and saved"
                      factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
                      pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
              </GlobalNamingResources>

              <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
                   a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
                   so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
                   Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
               -->
              <Service name="Catalina">

                <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
                <!--
                <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
                maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
                -->


                <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
                 and responses are returned. Documentation at :
                 Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html
                 Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
                 APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
                 Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
                -->
                <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                       connectionTimeout="20000"
                       redirectPort="8443" />
                <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
                <!--
                <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
                       port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                       connectionTimeout="20000"
                       redirectPort="8443" />
                -->
                <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
                 This connector uses the NIO implementation. The default
                 SSLImplementation will depend on the presence of the APR/native
                 library and the useOpenSSL attribute of the
                 AprLifecycleListener.
                 Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used regardless of
                 the SSLImplementation selected. JSSE style configuration is used below.
                -->
                <!--
                <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                       maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
                <SSLHostConfig>
                    <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                         type="RSA" />
                </SSLHostConfig>
                </Connector>
                -->
                <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 with HTTP/2
                 This connector uses the APR/native implementation which always uses
                 OpenSSL for TLS.
                 Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used. OpenSSL style
                 configuration is used below.
                -->
                <!--
                <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
                       maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
                <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
                <SSLHostConfig>
                    <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
                         certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"
                         certificateChainFile="conf/localhost-rsa-chain.pem"
                         type="RSA" />
                </SSLHostConfig>
                </Connector>
                -->

                <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
                <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


                <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
                 every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
                 analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
                 on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
                 Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

                <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
                <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
                -->
                <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

                  <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
                  /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
                  /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
                  <!--
                  <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
                  -->

                  <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
                   via a brute-force attack -->
                  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
                <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
                     resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
                     that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
                     available for use by the Realm.  -->
                <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
                       resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
                  </Realm>

                  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
                    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

                <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
                     Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
                <!--
                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
                -->

                <!-- Access log processes all example.
                     Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
                     Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
                       prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
                       pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

                  </Host>
                </Engine>
              </Service>
            </Server>
```

Any help or hint will be greatly appreciated it.

Comment: Please include the output of `netstat -nat`

Comment: Also make sure that in `tomcat/conf/server.xml` your connector is not bound only on 127.0.0.1 address.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that tomcat is not binding to a IPv4 address (according to `netstat` output, it is only bound to IPv6 - check first column).

In order to configure tomcat to bind to IPv4, refer to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/390840/how-does-one-get-tomcat-to-bind-to-ipv4-address). It describes the proper way to configure your tomcat JVM to `preferIPv4Stack` and `preferIPv4Addresses`.